# when i build "gomobile bind" a go project with opencv4 ,error come ,how can i solve

Tags: ios, opencv, gomobile

**Gomobile bind error**

[image: Screen Shot]

The array mean what, Anybody ever had this problem?

```
go build -tags ios -buildmode=c-archive -o/var/folders/vp/3ztk4jzn3hq35qfmp3qwrfm80000gp/T/gomobile-work135205628/faceTest-arm.a gobind failed: exit status 2
# gocv.io/x/gocv
In file included from calib3d.cpp:1:
In file included from ../../../../../gocv.io/x/gocv/calib3d.h:5:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.0/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.0/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:52:
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.0/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:659:10:
```

**fatal error**: 'array' file not found